# Regex.Matches exception of type 'System.ArgumentException'

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, asp.net-mvc

Trying to put inside the DataTable the matches I find in string:

```
DataTable dtListVar = new DataTable();

string pattern = @"\[([^\[\]]+)\]";

string inputText = "Find string inside brackets [C#.net] and [Vb.net] example.";

foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(inputText, pattern))
{
    DataRow dr = dtListVar.NewRow();
        dr["Var"] = m.Value.Replace('[', ' ').Replace(']', ' ');
        dr["Value"] = "";
        dtListVariables.Rows.Add(dr);
}
```

I find the element but when I want to assign in to the DataRow I have this exception:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred
>   in System.Data.dll

Comment: Usually exception Message gives some useful information about what's wrong!

Answer (score 0):

Your exception has nothing to do with your regular expression. Your exception message is coming from `System.Data`, not `System.Text.RegularExpression`.

You're creating a empty `DataTable`, then assigning data to a column that doesn't exist yet. You need to [define the schema of the data table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfx3s9wd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) before you attempt to assign data to it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should declare the columns Var and Values :

```
        DataTable dtListVar = new DataTable();
        dtListVar.Columns.Add("Var");
        dtListVar.Columns.Add("Value");
```

and use **dtListVar** and not **dtListVariables** on last line.

Btw, I would use an object instead of dataTable here.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
var row = dtListVar.NewRow();
dtListVar.Rows.Add(row);
...
```

Answer (score -3):

The pattern is wrong. "[" cannot go inside another "[".
Try "[(.*)]".

Comment: The pattern works, I can find the string with the pattern I want, and I can asign to a string variable, it's only when I try to add the dataRow